# Postgres deploy using Kubernetes not working

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am new to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), I created the deployment file for postgres as follow

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:xx.xx
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
                value: postgresdb
            -   name: POSTGRES_USER
                value: postgresadmin
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                value: admin123
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

and after deploying the postgres service on AKS, service got created.

```
abc@Azure:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.0.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          6h45m
postgres     NodePort    10.0.165.161   <none>        5432:30692/TCP   9m8s
```

But when I tried to get into the PSQL by using `psql -h localhost -U postgresadmin --password -p 30692 postgresdb`, it shows that connection refused.

```
abc@Azure:~$ psql -h localhost -U postgresadmin --password -p 30692 postgresdb
Password:
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 30692?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 30692?
```

Comment: You need to change the service into the type `LoadBalancer`.

Comment: In this case the database is running in the cloud, not on your local system; `localhost` won't be able to reach it.

Comment: I tried `LoadBalancer` and also used `EXTERNAL-IP`, but the problem is same

Comment: you need to whitelist your IPs in the AKS firewall rule maybe

Comment: What command do you use to connect the PostgreSQL? Do you change the localhost into the external IP of the service? And add the targetPort in the service ports.

Answer (score 2):

For your issue, it seems you want to expose the PostgreSQL to the Internet. As I see you made two mistakes.

First is the YMAL file, you need to change the service into below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
   - port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

The second is that the connect command. I think you connect the PostgreSQL in the Azure cloud shell, so you need to use the external IP of the service to connect:

```
psql -h external-IP -U postgresadmin --password -p 5432 postgresdb
```

Comment: `abc@Azure:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
postgres     LoadBalancer   10.0.221.108   13.91.192.202   5432:32516/TCP   23s
`
`abc@Azure:~$ psql -h 13.91.192.202 -U postgresadmin --password -p 5432 postgresdb
Password:
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection timed `

`abc@Azure:~$ psql -h 13.91.192.202 -U postgresadmin --password -p 32516 postgresdb
Password:
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection timed`

Comment: @RavindraGupta Can you check if the PostgreSQL run well?

Comment: Is there any changes in "volumes"

Comment: @RavindraGupta As I know, the mount path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is not empty. And if you use the Azure file share to mount to the path, then it will overwrite all the files in the path. So I recommend you use the Azure disk to mount.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only if I change the Service type from LoadBalancer to NodePort